# My question was downvoted and locked; what should I do to improve it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-delete, feedback

[generate a query that show the times that questions get wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347430/generate-a-query-that-show-the-times-that-questions-get-wrong)

This question has been around a while, and now I'm receiving so many downvotes that I even got banned from posting new questions. So I wanted to delete the question.

However, moderators are refusing to delete it, for whatever the reason.
What should I do in order to improve this question, or do you also think the question should be deleted / voted up / edited & how?

Comment: Now that it's locked, it cannot be voted on. You'll lose no more rep from it.

Comment: For better results in the future, show what you have tried. Your question appears to be a request for someone else to do your coding for you, which is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: But it does not make sense to keep it, since no one think its good...

Comment: @Adam 1) One person upvoted the question, so clearly "nobody thinks it's good" is false.  At least one person does.  2) There are several downvotes on answers, so apparently several people think there is value there.

Comment: I got that, the question I asked at that time is been conducted without been aware of such rule. But that simply is the nature of the question i am asking, there is no way I could fix it, except deletion, do you agree?

Comment: no idea why it was locked. There seem to have never been any answers deleted.

Comment: @Adam You were made aware of the fact that you should have included what you've tried within a few minutes of posting the question, in the form of several now-deleted comments, as well as several comments (also now deleted) from myself more recently.  You have ignored those requests to include what you've tried over the past several months.

Comment: @JanDvorak - "This post has been locked due to the high amount of off-topic comments generated. For extended discussions, please use chat."

Comment: If you're banned from asking new questions, don't delete that one. It will only make the problem worse.

Comment: @JanDvorak There was a long comment thread between Adam and myself that has since been deleted; that was the cause of the lock.

Comment: so, unlock (by a mod) and fix (by the asker)?

Comment: And don't just focus on this question. It's not a single questions that gets you banned. And it's not just fixing that question which will see you unbanned. Any upvotes you gain for any of your questions will help. Even making the good ones better might fix the problem. Give all your posts a good look and improve them if possible.

Comment: But it will help since its -5. thats a lot I need to get back. I am not a professional coder in any field yet, the questions mostly on the stackoverflow are too specific for the parts I am looking at. I am still studying, so will ahve more questions than answer. And this banning thing is killing me from improving.

Comment: @Adam Having a deleted question with a negative score will actually contribute *more* to you being question banned than having an undeleted question with a negative score.  Based on the [minimal] information publicly available, it's stated that this effect is actually rather considerable.

Comment: @LBT, I got this msg twice ( the most recent one is today), also, the question will become utterly redundant to provide any further information, because, if any of you got there and read about it, its about all the thing that required to answer the question. and the answerer did good on the answer. I have no idea how to fix a perfect simple question with any complexity on it. Am I have to lie about that I tried 'this...this...(by customize whoever answered question with a little mistake on it) " and then wala! I got an answer that appears 'fix the issue'!

Comment: .....that just seem so wrong and pathetic. Thats the problem. I have no idea why the question got so many down vote on while they seem neglected the answer's quality, but only focus on the question which is true, asking for an answer without show any prove of effort. But as I been repeating before, its seem pointless and meaningless to repeat the senario while I already konw the answer and, in this senario, a fake senario to prove the answer solve a "mistake" will be meaningless and waste of time.

Comment: @Adam Then listen to what we are telling you: improve your other questions! Stop focusing on that single one.

Comment: @Adam Stack Overflow isn't to help you (that’s a nice side benefit and probably why you're contributing but its not what SO is about). Each question and answer is expected to be helpful to many people (the first of which being you). By abandoning a question as soon as you have your answer you are breaking that cycle, you’re getting something for free without giving back, that is exactly what the question ban is designed to stop

Comment: @Adam While showing what you've tried is often a good way to show effort and get a good response, an alternative is to be very very clear about the problem. Most of your questions have a certain vague feeling about them. Given that you seemingly tried nothing I'd go down that route

Comment: @Adam If you're going to refuse to improve your questions because you already have an answer, then I guess that's fine.  It's reasonable enough to not want to put time and effort in when you see no perceptible benefit.  Instead think of it as improving your questions so that you don't get question banned, rather than to get you an answer.  Making your questions better isn't pointless if the result is you no longer being question banned.  As for why the community wants you to edit your questions and hence have the voting and q-ban system in place, see Richard's fantastic comment above mine.

Comment: @Adam Look at even your highest rated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15476424/oracle-insert-multiple-value-shows-error-message. Its "[Code] and it was: [Code] The table EXISTS and SETUP CORRECTLY. Error message shows ORA-01843: not a valid month. Where did I do it wrong?" Thats the entire question, no context, nothing

Comment: @Richard Tingle I feels sometimes... you neglected the fact people consider its useful because they know what situation they are in and what I am talking about. For whomever did not really meet the situation, that may not even get someone to understand it. Why would I have to explain to everyone about a question while, people have same problem and actually looking for it, understand?

Comment: Rules is that important when you have to explain in detail to everyone even the one who did not have the same problem? I stated everything necessary to fix the issue-> code, error reported, conditions clearified. I have no idea,why the most current 3 vote downs just for the contextual detail, and ignore the usability has been approved by people who actually realize its useful because they understand the situation?

Comment: @Adam, remember you did ask how you could improve. And im not saying it must be so clear anyone could understand but anyone in that area should be abld to understand,  for example this is one of your best questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428400/how-to-fire-an-event-on-dom-objects-dynamically-generated-after-page-load. I dont understand it as I don't know javascript but the context is clear and if I did know javascript im pretty confident it would make sense and be helpful. If you could make more of your questions like this all would be well